# insert query saying 'wrong type of data value'

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php query for a mysql db which collects basic info about pupils. There are three date fields - dob, doe, and dol - which I want the user to be able to leave blank or fill in yyyy-mm-dd.

```
INSERT INTO pupil_data (first_name,second_name,gender,registration,dob, doe, dol, ethnicity, eal, pup_prem, pup_prem_plus) 
VALUES ('aa','aa','male','kingfisher','','','','White British','yes','yes','yes' )`
```

The phpmyadmin sql editor comes back with `#1292 - Incorrect date value: '' for column 'dob' at row 1`

I have set the table up like this:

```
dob: type=date, null=no, default=1900-12-01
```

If I put dates like '2006-04-14' into the '' then it works. How can I get it to allow the user to leave it blank?

Thanks

Comment: Try inserting NULL instead of an empty string. It will then insert the default value.

Comment: You have defined null=no, try null=yes and then skip the values if empty (and remove the default).

Comment: Define it as NULL since it clearly can be empty according to you, Then insert NULL and not`''`

Answer (score 0):

A blank and NOT NULL `date` field should be '0000-00-00':

```
INSERT INTO pupil_data (first_name,second_name,gender,registration,dob, doe, dol, ethnicity, eal, pup_prem, pup_prem_plus) 
VALUES ('aa','aa','male','kingfisher','0000-00-00','','','White British','yes','yes','yes');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to allow an empty string as a `date` or `datetime` value, you need to set the [`ALLOW_INVALID_DATES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_allow_invalid_dates) SQL mode. It will then convert any invalid date to `0000-00-00`.